# Mutual support in Latin American wars of independence

Tags: military, spanish-empire, independence, decolonization, latin-america

Nascent Latin American countries expelled Spain with some mutual aid from each other. Between 1815 and 1822, independent Argentina and Chile sent newly acquired naval forces (under Bouchard, Brown, and Cochrane) to hit Spanish interests. They did damage up and down the Pacific coast. (Bouchard even went all the way around the world on his trip, ending up in Peru, where he was killed by one of his own slaves.)

Besides these big-ticket naval expeditions, what did the embryonic Latin American states and their citizens do to support each others' independence struggles?